# In java, How to access values of a class from other classes in thier differrent individual threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class named "Clock" which have implementing Runnable. In run() a infinite loop is started where thread sleeps for 100ms for each iteration and then changes a boolean value :"isOk".

There is another class "ConOne" in its seperate thread also having infinite loop and it tries to get the "isOk" boolean value from "Clock" class. but if value is false then "ConOne" has to wait at the thread to continue.

So I created to ConOne objects trying to access the boolean value from "Clock" class.
But it thorws a Exception describing that "current object is not a owner of thread".

Why is this happening?
And sorry for my English.

Here's code:
Clock class

```
public class Clock implements Runnable {
    boolean isOk;
    Thread t;
    
    Clock() {
        isOk = false;
        t = new Thread(this, "Clock_Thread");
    }
    
    void startClock() {
        t.start();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while(true) {
            try {
                t.sleep(100);
                System.out.println("Tick:" + i);
                if(isOk) {
                    isOk = false;
                } else {
                    isOk = true;
                    notify();
                }
                i++;
            } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException at Clock");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public boolean getPermit() {
        if (!isOk) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception at clock.getPermit()");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

ConOne class:

```
public class ConOne implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    Clock ct;
    
    ConOne(String name, Clock c) {
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        ct = c;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            ct.getPermit();
            repaint();
        }
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        System.out.println("Repainted On " + t);
    }
}
```

Class with main method:

```
public class Master {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clock clock = new Clock();
        ConOne con1 = new ConOne("Con11", clock);
        ConOne con2 = new ConOne("Con12", clock);
        
        clock.startClock();
        con1.t.start();
        con2.t.start();
    
        
    }
}
```

Here is the error:
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqADy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only call a wait on an object, if you have synchronized on that object.

So something like this:

```
synchronized(monitor){
   while(!condition)
      monitor.wait();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ve got things a bit twisted up I’m afraid, the notify() and wait() require ownership of the Clock object’s monitor. You can try to get the wait/notify semantics correct, but I recommend just using builtin tools, specifically a SynchronizedQueue. Clock can just hold one as a field and put 1 into it when isOk. The other thread can be put into a non-busy wait() with a simple take() from the queue, which will block until the Clock class puts something.